# Boostrap theme styling to wordpress conversion

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

i gotta problem in converting my bootstrap.css into wordpress via localhost. I already placed my **custom bootstrap theme** in the themes folder in wordpress. however, i followed some tutorial on how to easily convert this theme however, it can display the menu but no styling from my css.

here is my code for my **header.php**

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>

   <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id = "home">
      <div class="container" >
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-   target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top" ><strong>CODE.DESIGN.BUILD</strong></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#about" class = "page-scroll">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="#portfolio" class = "page-scroll">My Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div><!--end of Navbar-->
```

and here is my **style.css**

```
/*
Theme Name: BS3 Theme
Theme URI:http://
Description: My Bootstrap 3 Responsive Theme
Version: 1
Author: **
Author URI: http://
*/

@import url ("css/bootstrap.css");
```

and for my **index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

please do help and explain if there is such an answer. thank you stackpeople!

Comment: I also tried in the header.php in calling the css in this format..
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">
but still no styling. :(

Comment: first check your style.css loads correctly `body{background-color:red;}`, if its working your `@import url ("css/bootstrap.css");` not pointing correctly.

Comment: thank you for you response. i tried changing the color and its working. i still don't get it why my @import is not working. my folderstructure is

themes\myTheme
           css/
           fonts/
           js/
           index.php
           header.php
           footer.php

is there something wrong? i correctly placed my files in a manner. -.-

Comment: try `@import url ("../css/bootstrap.css");`

Comment: i tried it it still not working. ugh! i just followed this tutorial code from code. and still not working. how frustrating. its not linking to my css.

Comment: is your css folder have sub folders?

Comment: no its just css files. no more folders. i dont get it why its not linking to my css.

Answer (score 0):

The styling for wordpress site on your localhost is from a file called **style.css** , which is located in "localhost\wordpress\wp-content\themes\yourtheme\style.css" , so please try modifying this file for your desired styling. , for bootstrap theme you can try the same.

Comment: yes i was trying to import my bootstap theme but unfortunately it doesnt show my styling using @import url ('css/bootstrap.css'); it's not pointing to that location and thats the location of my bootstrap styling... 

thank you for the response

Comment: So, your first step is to make sure the css file is getting imported perfectly and the style is applied. try testing as Hareesh suggested.

Comment: yes i already tried what he suggested and its working the problem is my bootsrap.css is not linking to my styling.css. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wordpress on your local stack it may not be sending the CSS correctly depending on your server configuration.  You may want to try using your local IP address (usually 127.0.0.1) and putting that in on the settings screen.  Especially if local host isn't bound in your config file.  See here http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen for reference.  Replace both the site address and the Wordpress url address with your local IP address and the CSS should be served correctly.